# How to return py2neo related objects with fastapi using a response model?

Tags: neo4j, orm, fastapi, py2neo

I'm working on my backend app, with FastAPI as API server, and Py2neo to handle the database.

This is what I have:

```
# __nodes__
class User(GraphObject):
  name = Property()
  surname = Property()
  informations = RelatedTo("Information","DESCRIBE")

class Information(GraphObject):
  content = Property()
  user = RelatedFrom("User", "DESCRIBE")
   
# __schemas__
class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  surname: str
  informations: List[Information]

  class Config:
    orm_mode = True

class Information(BaseModel):
  content: str

  class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

Now the API code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from py2neo import Graph
import nodes
import schemas

app = FastAPI()
graph = Graph(uri="GDB_URI",auth=("GDB_USERNAME","GDB_PASSWORD"))

@app.get("/user", response_model=schemas.User)
def user_informations(id:int):
  user = nodes.User.match(graph,id).first()
  return user
```

The error I get then is:
pydantic.error_wr

```
appers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
response -> informations
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

Please what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `py2neo` use to represent associations? i.e. what is the type of `informations` inside the `user` object.

Comment: Have you looked at what's in the box before you return? Does this one conform to the return pattern?

Comment: @MatsLindh py2neo uses related objects; Like RelatedTo, or RelatedFrom. It depends on the relationship's direction. In my case, I used RelatedTo, to point to the user's information
Here is a link to the py2neo documentation on related objects https://py2neo.org/2020.1/ogm/index.html#related-objects

Comment: @fchancel of course I did. Everything is ok there. I don't think the problem comes from there

Comment: From what I can gather from a quick glance at the source code for [RelatedFrom](https://py2neo.org/2020.1/_modules/py2neo/ogm.html#RelatedFrom) it doesn't seem like it's directly an iterable? Does it need another level of indirection to reach the RelatedObjects-structure through `__get__`? I'm not familiar with py2neo, so forgive my inexperience